# WebAPI + JWT Token + OAuth - Client ID required?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, oauth, jwt

I'm developing an Angularjs website with a WebApi 2 backend which eventually will be utilised by mobile devices. I'm looking at the authentication side and I'm planning on using a JWT Token.

JWT is something new to me and the examples online appear to implement it different ways. Some show that in the ValidateClientAuthentication method you need to validate the ClientId and then the username and password in GrantResourceOwnerCredentials, where as other examples show just the user name and password getting sent to the Auth server and validated in ValidateClientAuthentication.

I'm guessing as angularjs is client side, it would be easy to get the client id, in which case what would be the need to send it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, this article http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/ answered my question.

If you're not using refresh tokens then you don't really need to send the client ID, but as you'd probably want to be using refresh tokens you'd be sending it. Never store the client secret in insecure apps like JS apps, or where the client secret could be reversed engineered out.

I'd definitely recommend the articles above, read them, implement them and you'll understand it all...or at least for that worked!